# Twitter api - trigger on new post?

Tags: twitter

I have never worked with the twitter api, so I have no idea if this is possible. What I want to do is to trigger a url everytime something new happens on a users timeline (?). Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it takes a bit of work.  You need to use the [twitter streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api), specifically the `follow` option.

From twitter:

> Example:  Create a file called ‘following’ that contains, exactly and
>   excluding the quotation marks: “follow=12,13,15,16,20,87” then
>   execute:
>
> curl -d @following https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json
>   -uAnyTwitterUser:Password.

Basically you pass a list of user ids you want to follow, open a long-lived connection, and twitter sends back to you anything that the user posts publicly.  You can monitor this connection and do things when a user posts something.

You have another option, called a [User Stream](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/user-streams) , which gets you *way* more information about when a user does *anything*, but it requires the user's approval, and a much more complex authentication process via oAuth.  So I would only use that if you need it.

How you're going to be keeping a persistant connection open to twitter is something very much dependent on your programming language and software.  In Python, I really like [tweepy](http://code.google.com/p/tweepy/), but even for python there are several different libraries, or you can just use curl or pycurl and do it yourself like in the example above.